# Mountain front derailleur for braze-on mount?

Tags: shimano, derailleur-front

I'm converting a Giant 2006 carbon road bike to flat bars. It has this setup:

Ultegra 6600 Triple, braze-on mount, bottom-pull, 52/39/30

105 5600 10-speed, 12-27

I have a set of SLX M670 10-speed shifters I'd like to use. The cable pull is (apparently) wrong on both ends, so I'm looking for replacement derailleurs.

What front derailleur can I use with these shifters that'll work with a braze-on mount? It's not clear to me which, if any, Dyna-sys derailleurs fit this frame. Or if any of them can handle the 52T ring.

The fallback is to give up and buy a set Shimano R770(?)/R780 or Microshift TS83-10. Microshift and R780 seem most likely to be compatible, but there's not a lot of documentation on the former.

Comment: A note on converting drop bar bikes to flat bar that you should be aware of - drop bar bikes have shorter frames because stem + hoods puts the rider's hands quite far forward. If you fit a flat bar it will be too far back, necessitating a long stem.

Comment: Indeed. Being rather short of torso, converted road frames often fit me better than the native flat-bar alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered cable pull adapter that would allow you use both MTB shifter and present road front derailleur?

[Jtek Shiftmate 7](http://www.jtekengineering.com/shiftmate/shiftmate-compatibility-charts-choices/) seems to do what you need.

I have not used any such adapters myself yet but I thought you should need about such possibility.

Comment: I did indeed, though nixed them for cost reasons. Good suggestion though.

Answer (score 2):

First, no MTB braze-on front derailleurs are currently made, and certainly none with the capacity to handle a 52/36t shift.

Second, your backup plan is the correct path. Get a road flat bar shifter set.

I have no hands on experience with the microshift shifters, but the SHIMANO Tiagra 4703 flat bar triple shifters, or the R770/780 sets are what you need.

Either will work, and the Tiagra are cheaper and more readily available in my experience.

Documentation can be found at http://si.shimano.com

Comment: That's about what I thought, thanks. I did discover the 4700-series and R770 wouldn't be drop-in solutions, though.

Answer (score 1):

This turned out to be complicated enough to merit another post. There is no 10S MTB ("Dyna-sys") front derailleur with a braze-on mount, so I've listed Shimano-compatible flat-bar road shifters.

http://blog.artscyclery.com/science-behind-the-magic/science-behind-the-magic-drivetrain-compatibility/

http://productinfo.shimano.com/download/pdf/com/3.0/en

These shifters will work with 10S Shimano road RDs, except for 4700:

- Shimano R460 | 2x10
- Shimano R780 | 2x10
- Shimano R783 | 3x10
- Shimano 4600 | 2x10
- Shimano 4603 | 3x10
- Microshift TS83-10 | 2/3x10
- Microshift R760-2 | 2x10
- Microshift R760-3 | 3x10

These shifters will work with 11S Shimano road RDs:

- Shimano RS700 | 2x11
- Shimano U5000 | 2x11
- Microshift R860 | 2x10
- Microshift R761 | 2x11

This shifter set works with a 4703 (and probably 4603) FD and a 4700 RD.

- Shimano 4703 | 3x10

This shifter set works with a 4700 FD and 4700 RD:

- Shimano 4700 | 2x10

These shifters work with a 9S Shimano FD and a 10S Shimano road RD, excluding 4700:

- Shimano R770 | 2x10
- Shimano R773 | 3x10

Comment: Where did you find info saying that the SL 4603/4703 were 11 speed? They appear to be clearly designated as 10 speed triple?

Comment: 4600 is cross-compatible with other Shimano 10-speed kit except for 4700. 4700 is mostly just compatible with itself. The cable pull of the rear shifter now matches Shimano's 11S road lineup, as does the front shifter for the double. The 4700 triple shifter seems to retain 4600's cable pull.

Comment: Yes, because there is no 11 speed triple, if I understand correctly. But since all you need is the front derailleur, the 4700 or 4600 should work. Correct?

Comment: Or is it because you want front derailleur and shifters? In which case, you may need to match the front shifter to the front derailleur, and use a different set for the rear. Or also update the rear derailleur.

Comment: There were a lot of ways I could have solved this, but none with a front MTB shifter above 9S. I ended up getting a good deal on Tiagra 4603; it was a tossup between that and Microshift's TS83-10 at the same price.